# jquery 'this' used in a function problem

Tags: jquery

I am writing a basic web app, this has some list elements that I need to be able to click on the entire LI that surrounds each one to select the radio button held within, and only ensure the one I have clicked is selected. I can do this writing the code within the .click callback, however if I try to call the same code from a named function it falls down, I believe this is something to do with the "this" reference I am using, however I cannot seem to fix it.

The HTML is

```
<ul> 
  <form id="healthCheckAge" name="healthCheckAge"> 
    <li> <input type="radio" name="eighteen" value="18-30" />18-30 </li> 
    <li> <input type="radio" name="thirtyone" value="31-45" />31-45 </li> 
    <li> <input type="radio" name="fourtysix" value="46-65" />46-65 </li> 
    <li> <input type="radio" name="sixtyfive" value="65+" />65+</li> 
  </form> 
</ul>
```

And the JavaScript is

```
function li_click(){
  //set the vars for the selectors
  var listInputs = $('#healthCheckAge li input');
  var clicked = listInputs.attr('name');
  //loop on all the li children to see if they match the clicked LI - if not ensure that they are unchecked and faded
  $(listInputs).each(function(index,Element){
    $(listInputs).attr('checked',false).parent().addClass('selected');
  });
  //set the radio button to checked and apply a style to it, while removing this from any other checked radio buttoon
  if($(listInputs).attr('name')==clicked){
    $(this).children().attr('checked','true').parent().removeClass('selected'); 
  } 
}

$('#healthCheckAge li').click(function(){
  li_click();                                 
});
```

I think the problem is that when I call the very last conditional statement the 'this' is not reflecting what I need.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Firebug or Chrome dev tools?

Comment: I have been developing for iPad alone so have been using Safari, although I have chrome and this should work in there. I have been running  JSLint for jquery in safari and the console complains that" no elements were found with the selector 'undefined'" which I dont get if I run the same code in the .click callback. Also if I run `if($(listInputs).attr('name')==clicked){alert(this.nodeName)      $(this).children().attr('checked','true').parent().removeClass('selected'); }`
I get undefined on the node name -  So i kinda need to find a way to make this be related to the conditional statement :/

Comment: The best way to avoid problems in situations where this will be needed throughout a complex function is to set a variable to the valye of this like `var __this = $(this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the element to the function:

```
function lol(element){
  //set the vars for the selectors
  var listInputs = $('#healthCheckAge li input');
  var clicked = listInputs.attr('name');
  //loop on all the li children to see if they match the clicked LI - if not ensure that they are unchecked and faded
  $(listInputs).each(function(index,Element){
    $(listInputs).attr('checked',false).parent().addClass('selected');
  });
  //set the radio button to checked and apply a style to it, while removing this from any other checked radio buttoon
  if($(listInputs).attr('name')==clicked){
    $(element).children().attr('checked','true').parent().removeClass('selected'); 
  } 
}
  $('#healthCheckAge li').click(function(){
    lol(this);                                
  });
```

Inside the click handler, `this` refers to the element, but inside `lol` it points to the owner of the function, which is the global `window` object.

Comment: Thanks! I have been passing allsorts to this to try and solve it, completely didn't think to pass the click target as a var. Thanks!!!

Comment: @user499846, you could pass the element to the function, but see my answer below too. You can directly bind the "this" to what you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the scope of lol() to the "this" that jQuery sets, using `call`, which is a method that is available to all functions:

```
$('#healthCheckAge li').click(function(){
    lol.call(this);                                
});
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to keep your function the way it is and do:

```
$('#healthCheckAge li').click( li_click );
```

Now `this` is the element that received the event, and you can still define the `event` parameter in the function if need be.

It is the exact equivalent of passing the function directly as the argument to the `click()` method.